# Sample Silverlight 4 projects

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, projects, sample

I am looking to get my hands wet with Silverlight 4. I was wondering if someone can recommend a sample silverlight 4 project that I can do (home project) to get my confidence level up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some of the resources I used to get started:

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/handsonlabs/

Following the labs in the first link is a great way to get started, there are videos as well as step-by-step instructions.

Apparently I am not cool enough yet to post multiple hyperlinks so I will try to post these in three different postings.

I am also not cool enough to post multiple answers yet. :|